# Можно ли на 1 ip создать несколько серверов?

Tags: сервер

Пытаюсь разобраться с устройством серверов. Для создания сервера нужны 2 вещи : ip и порт, т.е. используя 1 ip, но 2 разных открытых порта, я могу создать 2 сервера? Таким образом, 1 порт = 1 сервер?

Comment: Можете, пока порты не кончатся

Comment: Зависит от того что вы называете сервером. Например на одном 80 порту по http можно обслуживать хоть миллион разных доменов (которые часто считают серверами)

Comment: @AlexeyTen А https?

Comment: Тоже, но чуть сложнее

Comment: А можно ли создать сервер на сервере? Я правильно понимаю, что это делается именно через домены?

Comment: @Bitchdragon что вы имеете в виду под фразой «сервер на сервере»?

Comment: Просто вчера читал в статье, что на хостинге можно ставить SQL-сервер, это считается "сервером на сервере"?

Comment: @Bitchdragon вы ж уже и так поставили себе MySQL-сервер. Я не совсем понимаю, какой смысл употреблять здесь фразу «сервер на сервере»

Comment: Да нет, это просто теоретический вопрос, я его на практике применять не буду, у меня уже работает сервер так, как я хотел

Comment: Кажется вы путаете понятия. Есть сервер как «компьютер» (железный или виртуальный). И есть сервер как программа — веб сервер, SQL сервер, игровой сервер и т. п.